# Is Dart available for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: dart, raspberry-pi

Is there a standard way to run a Dart VM on a Raspberry Pi?
I haven't found any information about that in mailing lists.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/hWDpXMjVqOI as of April, it was still a work in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, DartVM is on R-Pi.

It can be downloaded from this link ( *labelled as Linux ARMv7* ):
https://www.dartlang.org/install/archive

Answer (score 4):

Dart ARMv7 builds are now available via the dart manual download page on the dart website https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/archive/

Old Raspberry Pi is an ARMv6 and so only the new Raspberry Pi 2, ARMv7 is supported by these dartlang SDK build.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the arm port of the Dart VM is still being developed (though answers from Devoxx imply it is getting close). However nothing prevents you from running a web server on PI and serving up client side dart code and JavaScript compiled dart code for client side apps.

Answer (score 2):

**Standard... not yet** as far as I know. So I went ahead and built it:

https://plus.google.com/115544353187538281728/posts/bDGc2BzHwZ5

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi builds are now built and published for each version of Dart.

They are not currently listed on the website but you can download them from here:

http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/1.12.2/sdk/